# Linux MV command failing from Script - using variables

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, mv

I'm trying to move files from within a bash script,

I have the source and destination saved to variables:

```
source='/Users/usr/Downloads/Drop/test\ movie.m4v'
dest='/Users/usr/Downloads/Movies/test\ movie.m4v'
```

And I'm running:

```
mv $source $dest
```

I get the output:

```
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
   mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

What am I doing wrong!?

The files I'm moving may or may not contain spaces in their paths. I'm using sed to add the escape char before the space.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways to deal with filenames that contain spaces, one quick solution might be to wrap the variables in the `mv` command in quotes:

```
#!/bin/bash

source=/path/to/file\ with\ space
dest=/path/to/file\ with\ space2

mv "$source" "$dest"
```

Comment: If you do this then remove the '\' escape chars

Comment: Or remove the single quotes... so either way, works. Escaping is definitely uglier and perhaps more of a pain :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using escape chars I'm just wrapping my variables in quotes, so:

```
source='/Users/usr/Downloads/Drop/test movie.m4v'
dest='/Users/usr/Downloads/Movies/test movie.m4v'

mv "$source" "$dest"
```